# Is there a way to apply the minimum date and related values from another column based on criteria in Power Query?

Tags: excel, powerquery

I have a rather large power query (35k rows but lots of columns) and I face a situation where I sometimes have a single sales order tying to multiple stock numbers where I get multiple planned dates associated with multiple factories.  I need to apply the earliest planned date - along with its associated factory to all lines of that sales order.  I have looked into merging the query to itself - and this does seem to be able to get to the minimum planned date.  However that takes a VERY long time and I still can't seem to figure out how to also get the associated factory of that date and apply to all the rows of that sales order.

Here is some sample data:

[image]

What I need to do is apply the Planned Date and Factory information in red to all the other lines of the SO #.  Is this something tht can be done in Power Query?

Comment: Yes, it is.  If you need more focused assistance, I suggest reading the HELP topics for [How do I Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and also [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Then **edit your question** to provide additional information and a method for use to reproduce your problem.  It is likely you could use `Group` and then return the minimum Planned Date, then reexpand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is some MCode you may be able to adapt to your real data.

It

- uses the data you show as a starting point
- Groups by SOP#
- Determines the first date and associated factory
- Re-expands the table (except for the original date/factory columns

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table5"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"SO#", Int64.Type}, {"Stock #", Int64.Type}, {"Planned Date", type date}, {"Factory", type text}}),

//Group by SO#
// then return minimum date and corresonding factory
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Changed Type", {"SO#"}, {
        {"All", each _, type table [#"SO#"=nullable number, #"Stock #"=nullable number, Planned Date=nullable date, Factory=nullable text]},
        {"Planned Date", each List.Min([Planned Date]), Date.Type},
        {"Factory", (t)=> List.Range(t[Factory],List.PositionOf(t[Planned Date],List.Min(t[Planned Date])),1){0}, Text.Type}
    }),

//Expand the table (except for the original date and factory columns
    #"Expanded All" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "All", {"Stock #"}, {"Stock #"})
in
    #"Expanded All"
```

[image]